# How to remove all letters from the beginning of the string in SQL server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to remove the letters **from the beginning of the string only** from the `dbo.ProductCodes table`.

I have:

| ProductCode |
| --- |
| **XXX**8361229**BB** |
| **XY**0060482**AB** |
| **CR**0058882**A**1 |
| **CPR**777093219 |
| **CPCODE**0002835 |

I want:

| ProductCode |
| --- |
| 8361229**BB** |
| 0060482**AB** |
| 0058882**A**1 |
| 777093219 |
| 0002835 |

If the letters were only at the beginning of the string, I could remove all letters using regex `[^a-zA-z]`. The problem is that letters appear not only at the beginning of the string.

EDIT: Also, I'd like to apply some exclusions to this logic. For instance, if the prefix is 'AA' or 'Q' or 'QA', I don't want to remove letters from the beginning of the string. Examples: Q12345, AA1234S, QA12345

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: And what do you want if a string is _all_ letters and _no_ numbers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Updated for changed requirements:

```
SELECT ProductCode,
  Adjusted = SUBSTRING(ProductCode, 
    CASE WHEN ProductCode NOT LIKE 'Q%'
          AND ProductCode NOT LIKE 'QA%'
          AND ProductCode NOT LIKE 'AA%' THEN
    PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', ProductCode+'0')
    ELSE 1 END, 255)
FROM dbo.ProductCodes;
```

- Example [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=0e4d759fa3f7c4f515b1452aa228f270) also deals with no letters and all letters (empty result).

Comment: Thank you Aaron, it worked! Is it possible to apply some exclusions to this logic? For instance, if the prefix is 'AA' or 'Q' or 'QA', I don't want to remove letters from the beginning of the string. Examples: Q12345, AA1234S, QA12345

Comment: Apologies Aaron, there are no other hidden requirements. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Rather than `SUBSTRING`, I would personally use `STUFF`, as then you don't have to define a length of how many characters you want to retain, meaning that this will work for any length string. I also switch to looking for the first non-alpha character, rather than the first number, just to show the difference.

```sql
SELECT ProductCode,
       STUFF(ProductCode, 1, ISNULL(NULLIF(PATINDEX('%[^A-z]%', ProductCode),0)-1,0),'')
FROM dbo.ProductCodes;
```

Comment: The first non-alpha character though could be `-` or `_` or `<poop emoji>`.

Comment: I specifically state I do this to just show the other methodology, @AaronBertrand , compared to looking for the first numerical character. The OP doesn't actually state if other characters could appear.

Comment: Yep, I'm not complaining to you, just making sure the OP is aware that other characters might trip that up, that's all.

Comment: Fair enough, I thought you were highlighting this to me.

Comment: I don't know if I've ever needed to tell you anything my friend, it's almost always for the OP (because they almost always furnish incomplete information in the question and then complain about undeclared edge cases).

Comment: Even if you're never directly told me anything, I've certainly learned  (and continue to) from your articles over the years, @AaronBertrand . :)

Comment: *"because they almost always furnish incomplete information in the question and then complain about undeclared edge cases"* can I borrow that crystal ball of yours too? Literally [17 seconds later](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71310335/how-to-remove-all-letters-from-the-beginning-of-the-string-in-sql-server/71310661?noredirect=1#comment126048948_71310448)...